# Use of X-rays in Oil Drop Experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, history

Why did Millikan use X-rays and not any other electromagnetic wave to ionize the oil drops ?

Comment: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: I wonder if [hsm.se] would be a more appropriate venue for this question